# Value error: could not convert string to float for jpg images in Tensorflow

Tags: image, tensorflow, feed, training-data

I would like to train a simple graph in Tensorflow with labelled images.

Here is the code:

```
images_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_list_train, dtype=dtypes.string)
labels_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(label_list_train, dtype=dtypes.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
      init.run()
      sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: images_train.eval(), y: labels_train.eval()})
```

Unfortunally, it doesn't recognize the data and here is the error message:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
>   b'C:/Users/Nicolas/Documents/Photos3/im_photo_224.jpg'

Any idea to solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance,

Nicolas

Comment: You are passing the filename of the image as an input to your NN. You should open and read them before converting them to the expected input tensor type.

Comment: Thanks Manolo, I suppose I have to set an array of images as input of the feed_dict: Is it correct? Or is it better to use a for loop image by image?

Comment: Usually you feed several images in a batch for performance reasons. GPUs are optimized for this kind of task.

Comment: Thanks again. The only example I've found is not directly applicable for any batch (function "next_batch"): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py - Do you have a simple example of a batch code?